# VBA - Replace blank cells

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have to replace each blank cell in the column BM with the data in this same row in column DN.
I have written that:

```
Columns("BM:BM").Select
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select
Selection.FormulaR1C1 = "=DN2"
```

But the "=DN2" ends like "=@'DN2'" in every cell. Which makes an error. 
Does someone know how could I get the cell in DN from the same row please?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Change `.FormulaR1C1` to `.Formula`

Comment: You might benefit from reading 
[How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).

Comment: @ScottCraner - you might want to use an actual `.FormulaR1C1` here - using a hard-coded row as in `DN2` might not work.

Comment: As @BigBen stated maybe change the formula to an actual `R1C1` format: `"=RC118"`  the issue is that you are mixing R1C1 and A1 notation.

Comment: @ScottCraner Why don't you post it as a valid answer? I think that is the correct solution to the problem.

Comment: This should be @BigBen's answer not mine.

Comment: @ScottCraner - go ahead and post :-)

Comment: This is a lot to process on a whole column. You sure you need it all? Also, would you really need formulas, or rather values? In other words, are you going to **need** these formulas and therefor process data twice?

Comment: @JvdV no `SpecialCells` will limit to `UsedRange` so it doesn't fill all the rows to the bottom. Give it a try.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ If that is so (and I do believe you are right), this might be even more problematic. What if data in any other column actually **exceeds** (by far) the last used row in column BM? You'll end up with ton's of rows populated with formulas where you might not want them. I'd rather go with the last used row from column `DN` and take it from there if that's the case =)

Comment: @JvdV well, that's true. Depends on how the rest of the data looks like. But limiting it to the last used row of DN might definitely be a solid solution. Good point.

Answer (score 4):

If you are going to `R1C1` then make the Formula `R1C1`

```
If Application.CountA(ActiveSheet.Range("BM:BM"))<> ActiveSheet.Rows.Count Then
    ActiveSheet.Range("BM:BM").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC118"
End If
```

Answer (score 4):

Another way to do this

```
Dim rng As Range

On Error Resume Next
Set rng = Columns("BM:BM").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
On Error GoTo 0

If Not rng Is Nothing Then
    rng.Formula = "=DN" & rng.Row
End If
```

BTW if you are using `SpecialCells`, use error handling else your code will crash when it doesn't find those cells

Answer (score 2):

Here are my two cents. I would drop the idea of using `SpecialCells` on whole columns altogether. If you want to go with `SpecialCells` then atleast create a `Range` within the `BM` column first to use it on. If any column exceeds the rows of interest you'll end up with values in places you really don't want (formulas in your case).

Here is a small example spanning `A1:C5`:

[image]

Our area of interest is column `B:B` where, if empty, we need the values from column `C:C`

When we run code using `SpecialCells`, for example:

```
Columns("B:B").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC3"
```

We will end up with:

[image]

What we see is that `SpecialCells` makes use of `UsedRange` (as @Peh rightfully mentioned in the comment section) and therefor is highly unreliable when used like that. There is a risk of ending up with values/formulas where you don't want them. I suggest making use of the last used row from column `C:C` (or in your case `DN`) and go from there. So allready much saver would be something like:

```
.Range("BM1:BM" & <LastUsedRowOfDN>).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC118"
```

Comment: I give you 10 rep for your two cents :-)

Comment: Ha, that's rather cheap for 10 whole rep @BigBen

Comment: English is weird - we have the expression "Here are my two cents" but also "A penny for your thoughts." Apparently we can't figure out the worth.